# Unable to set the text for TextView of different layout from the MainActivity

Tags: android, xml

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);
            user_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.user_name);

            username = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            Log.d("USERNAME ", username);
            user_name.setText(username);
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="@string/Uname"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here, I'm receiving intent from another activity and everything goes right without any error. But, the thing is I'm unable to update the **TextView** of **nav_header_main.xml** by using *user_name.setText(username);*

Comment: Can you post a log? An Error log or something more? Looking at code you're doing things right

Comment: `vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);` does not belong to the Activity's view hierarchy.  You have a valid java object which is not at screen

Comment: Are you able to see the value in Log.d("USERNAME ", username); this line ??????

Comment: Yes, I'm able to see the log and the logcat doesn't show any errors...

Comment: How to know which java object i'm having and I have searched so many forums and found this method to access a different layout from main activity @Blackbelt

Comment: that doesn't access anything. It creates an Android View Object starting from a static layout.

Comment: I'm receiving the intent from another activity and using this _setText()_ to update the TextView. I don't know why, but i'm unable to update the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Get your NavigationView

`NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view)`

Try getting your header view by inflating like this

`View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main)`

get your textView like below

`user_name = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This solved the problem but instead of replacing it, it is creating the similar view as a result i ended up having two same views

Comment: @PraneetPabolu Happy to hear that. Please accept my answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.
Instead of inflating a new headerView, we can reference it via

> getHeaderView()

```
    TextView user_name;
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    View headerView= navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    user_name = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    user_name.setText("Whatever the name is!");
```

The 0 in the getHeaderView() argument is the index of the header in your navigationView; generally when you have one header it is better to index it at 0.